# What is the provenance of the nucleosynthesized material in our solar system?

Tags: astronomy

Check me on this premise - eventing heavier than hydrogen was formed at the heart of another star that exploded.

If so, where was that star, and what remains of it (other than us)? What is the evidence for that?

Comment: How does this relate to space exploration? There's a nice astronomy stack exchange over that way -->

Comment: Ah yes, that's probably a better venue.

Comment: Is there an easy way to migrate it there?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens ... I believe it is more correct that everything up to iron on the periodic table was made in an exploding star. Heavier nuclei require collisions of superdense objects like neutron stars or black holes. See what the astronomy folks say.

Comment: If the SE overlords have configured this SE site to do so, the mods of this site can migrate your question to astronomy SE.  But given that your question is very short and simple, a quick cut and paste will do the job just dandy.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/16313/16685 And on a related note, https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43425/16685

Comment: BTW, stars don't have to explode to return matter to the interstellar medium. Eg, over its lifetime the Sun will lose ~50% of its mass, and end its life as a white dwarf.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to Space Exploration.

Comment: That everything that is "heavier than hydrogen formed at the heart of another star that exploded" is not true. The primordial elements are hydrogen, helium, and a tiny bit of lithium. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis.

Comment: @Woody the R and S nucleosynthesis processes can occur in stars and supernovae to produce surprisingly heavy elements, eg. neodymium.

Comment: @StarfishPrime ... I believe current thinking (from gravitational wave studies)  is that supernovae produce little R synthesis, and most of it occurs in neutron star/black hole mergers. But I'm way outside my pay grade with this topic.

Comment: You may find these interesting: [Are we really star-stuff from the interior of collapsing stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29136/7982) and [Are binary neutron star mergers needed to explain the abundance of gold?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23162/7982)